# Extract numbers in PHP from a string + ignoring the <sup> content

Tags: php

I have 2 type of strings:

1. 356 Hello World!
2. 6 Hello France! <sup>2,5</sup>

I use this code to extract the number, I actually need only the numbers from the begining

```
$int_image_id = (int) filter_var(get_the_title(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

the result is:

1. 356
2. 625 (but it should be 6)

Comment: What about `$int_image_id = (int)get_the_title();`???

Answer (score 2):

If the number always prefixes the string, you can also simply use [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

```
$int_image_id = intval(get_the_title());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help:

```
$int_image_id = (int) get_the_title();
```

if `$int_image_id = '6 Hello France! 2,5';`

Output:

```
6
```

I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use regex
`preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $matches);`
the above line will search for digits and add them to the `$matches` array.

```
<?php
$string = '6 Hello France! 2,5';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches)
?>
```